# A knot invariant which highlights the unknot

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

Is there a knot (link) invariant, or a combination of them which discern the unknot (unlink) from any other knot (link)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, however they are not known to be computable in polynomial time.  A quick an incomplete survey:

- The Seifert genus of a knot is $0$ if and only if it is unknotted.
- The fundamental group of the knot complement (the *knot group*) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if the knot is unknotted.
- The A-polynomial (not to be confused with the Alexander polynomial), which has to do with homomorphisms of the knot group to $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{C}$.
- Both knot Floer homology and Khovanov homology detect unknots.
- For knots with 10 or fewer crossings, the Alexander polynomial suffices.

The unknotting problem is known to be in NP and coNP.  That means, given a knot presented in some manner, someone can give you a proof that the knot is either knotted or unknotted that takes polynomial time to verify.

Wikipedia has [a list of unknotting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknotting_problem#Unknotting_algorithms).  Approaches include:

- enumerating Seifert surfaces to find a disk that bounds the knot.
- exhaustively trying all sequences of Reidemeister moves of a diagram up to a certain polynomial number of steps.
- exhaustively trying all sequences of Pachner moves of a triangulation of the knot complement up to a certain polynomial number of steps, until it is obviously an unknot triangulation.
- use [Dynnikov's result](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208153v3) that arc presentations (grid diagrams) for an unknot can be monotonically simplified, so try all monotonic simplifications.

There are also a number of invariants where whether it can detect unknots is an open question, such as the Jones polynomial, the HOMFLY polynomial, and finite-type (Vassiliev) invariants.